# Error while executing query in C#, SQL Server: trying to update if value already present else insert

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to execute a query with a condition like if username already present then update the row, else insert username and password.

This is my code below:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users(Username,Password) VALUES(@User,@password) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Username=VALUES(Username), Password=VALUES(Password)"))
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", TextBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Pwd);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I got the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong in this. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: There's no such thing as `ON DUPLICATE KEY` in SQL Server (not sure where you got this from.....)

Comment: oh i see i got the DUPLICATE KEY part from a question similar to this ,it was in one of the answers . I am using this to update password ,but problem is if user already exists duplicate entries of the user with different passwords are being stored .I used hashing and salt string ,for the password,i just copied the part where the error was instead of entire code.i read the article you gave ,i didnt know about this issue of AddwithValue() thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server you need to use a query something like this:

```
-- check if exists (by username) - if found, update password
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE Username = @User)
   UPDATE dbo.Users
   SET Password = @password
   WHERE Username = @User
ELSE
   INSERT INTO dbo.Users(Username, Password) 
   VALUES(@User, @password)
```

And as mentioned in my comments - do **not** use the `.AddWithValue` function (see linked blog post for details) but use this instead:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextBox3.Text;
```

And also, please ***do not*** store your passwords in ***clear text*** in the database!

Comment: String query = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE     Username = @ User)
   UPDATE Users
   SET Password = @password
   WHERE Username = @ User
ELSE
   INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password) 
   VALUES(@ User, @password)";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))                             I used the code you gave and used to debug points to check if the code is executing ,and it was, still it is not updating or Inserting the values .I cant run the query in SQL server cause each time i open the query window VSudio restarts,i am using trial version of Visual Studio

Comment: I purposely kept that when posting this question ,@User is also used by stack overflow website and it didnt allow me to post the data like that so i kept a space between @ and user ,but in code i kept it correctly

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using MySQL syntax. I don't think SQL Server has ON DUPLICATE KEY. You'd probably want a [MERGE statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

@marc_s

```
 String query = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE     Username = @ User)
       UPDATE Users
       SET Password = @password
       WHERE Username = @ User
    ELSE
       INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password) 
       VALUES(@ User, @password)";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
```

I used the code you gave and used to debug points to check if the code is executing ,and it was, still it is not updating or Inserting the values .I cant run the query in SQL server cause each time i open the query window VSudio restarts,i am using trial version of Visual Studio

Comment: And are you adding the parameter values for `@User` and `@password`, too?

Comment: What does your connection string look like??

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|customer.mdf;User ID='krishna-PC';Password='';Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

Comment: I'm sorry, I really cannot find any problem. I created a "UserTest" table in my SQL Server 2014 (**on the server** - not fiddling around with `.mdf` files floating around.....), and I used this exact query that I gave you, and I can easily insert new users with their password, and update existing users to a new password - the code works just fine - not sure what the problem at your end is,.....

Comment: I found the mistake marc_s,in PageLoad i had kept TextBox3.Text="",and because of that the username was always blank ,and due to which the value werent updating in database correctly.Thanks for all the help marc_s